# Finding the length of the longest continuous series of positive numbers in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0

Example:

```
 2,3,0,1,-5,10,11,12
```

The largest length of positive numbers is 3.

I have the code to check the array but do not understand how exactly i can make an `int` to hold the length and than restart if for example the sequence stops.

Comment: Have you read anything about programming? If yes, read more..

Comment: I'm assuming this is a homework question as I'm not seeing the practical application of this.  If it is, you should pay more attention in class, or rephrase your question using code examples.  Defining an `int` (which you say you don't know how to do) was probably in lesson 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    int counter = 0;
    int longestCounter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > 0) counter++;
        else
        {
            if ( counter > longestCounter ) longestCounter = counter;
            counter = 0; 
        }
    }
    if ( counter > longestCounter ) longestCounter = counter;
```

Comment: You're right, I've corrected this

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this answer as an alternative. You can simply use a `for`-loop like this (very similar to the other answers, just more compact):

```
int longestLen = 0, currentLen = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    currentLen = array[i] > 0 ? currentLen + 1 : 0;
    longestLen = Math.Max(currentLen, longestLen);
}
Console.WriteLine(longestLen); // 3
```

Or Linq, like this:

```
int longestLen = array.Aggregate(
    new { c = 0, m = 0 }, 
    (x, n) => new { c = n = (n > 0 ? x.c + 1 : 0), m = Math.Max(n, x.m) }, 
    x => x.m);
Console.WriteLine(longestLen); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// similar to the "Sliding Windows Algorithm" in "Programming Pearls"
int i, current, maxSoFar;

current = 0;
maxSoFar = 0;
for (i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    if (a[i] > 0)
    {
        current = current + 1;

        if (current > maxSoFar)
        {
            maxSoFar = current;
        }
    } else {
        current = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `a` . At least post a compilable, readable code if you want to answer someone's homework.